# PHP Warning: Error while sending INIT_DB packet. PID=3629

Tags: php, mysql

My automation code encountered a subject-like problem when calling a particular function.
It occurs randomly during execution, not immediately after execution, and after the problem occurs, the error "mysql_num_rows() expect parameters 1 to be resource, boolean given in" occurs and normal behavior is not performed.

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.
PHP version is 5.6.40.
Mysql version is 5.7.38.

The problematic function code.

```
$conn = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","ID","PW");
if($conn ==NULL)
{
         echo "<script> alert(\" Error : DB 연결 에러입니다. 불편을 드려 죄송합니다. 관리자에게 문의 하십시요\");   </script>";
         return $conn;
}
mysql_select_db("mysql");

mysql_query("set session character_set_connection=utf8;");
mysql_query("set session character_set_results=utf8;");
mysql_query("set session character_set_client=utf8;");

$dbname = "test_table";
$str = "select * from $dbname where 1";
$leak_result = mysql_query($str);
$leak_num1 = mysql_num_rows($leak_result);
```

Please give me a solution.

Comment: First, don't use `mysql_query`. It is old, bad, and going away. Use the `mysqli_` functions or PDO instead. ("i" is for "improved"). As for your question, that function returns `false` if there was an error (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). So after you do the query, you should check if the result is false. `mysqli_num_rows` is not going to work if there was an error. So if the result was false, `mysqli_error()` will tell you why,

Comment: In fact, don't use php 5.6. It is no longer supported, and if there are security flaws in that version, they will not be fixed.

Comment: @Jerry Thank you.
Only the function in question was written in mysql. I will modify it to mysqli and try again.

Answer (score 0):

**This error is appearing because of the maximum number of database connection requests have made**.

Your Ubuntu 18 with PHP server it's making a lot of requests.

The "PID=3629" you read it's the **Process Id** that generates the error.

The method you are using `mysql_query` it's old and deprecated.

Now PHP uses `mysqli` method like this

```
$connect = mysqli_connect( $host, $user, $pass, $DBname );
$query = 'SELECT .... '; //here your query
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query);
```

Like said in comments, if there's an error `mysqli_query` gives back a false result

[PHP OFFICIAL SITE](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

If you want a more complete answer on the error use the `mysqli_error()` function.

Good luck